# Rightward - leftward -

Tags: prepositions, verbs

> He was driving leftward
>
> They were walking rightward
>
> I was looking rightward
>
> Turn rightward when you get to the corner
>
> He was looking upward

Do these sentences sound fine grammatically? And why are these prepositions not used? Nowadays 'Turn right' would be the most suitable, but why? Was it only because people got used to this or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we do say "upward" and "downward", ["rightward" and "leftward" are practically never used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=upward%2Cdownward%2Crightward%2C+leftward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  In this case there is really no "why", that's just how it *is*.

If you were to use them in a sentence people would understand what you mean, but it would not be idiomatic.  Instead use "to the left" or "to the right".

Comment: So,  although not idiomatically, they are fine grammatically?

Comment: Although it's rare they are used so yeah, probably